# Define @Default producer if no other is defined

Tags: java, wildfly, cdi

When I have a bean producer which - in some environments - is provided, how can I annotate mine to be available as `@Default` if no other is?

Given the producer method

```
@Produces 
public Foo produce()
```

and another producer method in code I don't control:

```
@Produces 
public Foo produceIt()
```

both have an implicit @Default annotation and clash. 
But the second one is not available in all environments.

Edit: so I added another Qualifier, @FooProducer to the first one (I control), which makes it work when the second one is available - but this removes the implicit @Default so there is **NO** producer (type matches but none with @Default found) available if the second one is not on the classath.

How to annotate the first producer to be the *default* if the second one is *not* available, and to not clash if there is another default producer?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the behaviour if you didn't annotate your first method with @Default? Or do you have even more producers?

Comment: If the problem is "use my implementation (or producer) for Foo, if my implementation (or producer) is in the classpath", then the `@Specializes` annotation might be the solution. See CDI 2.0 specification, section 3.2.3! In short, you class must extend the class you do not control, override the producer method and annotate it with `@Specializes @Produces`.

Comment: @PerHuss true, I update the question to make it more clear

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos .. extending is not an option, the class is not known then. Plus it's CDI 1.x :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Weld](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#alternatives) it looks like declaring your producer an @Alternative and enabling it globally with any @Priority should do the trick:

```
@Priority(100)
public class YourFactory {

    @Produces @Alternative
    public Foo produce() 
}
```

Comment: "An alternative is not available for injection, lookup or EL resolution to classes or JSP/JSF pages in a module unless the module is a bean archive and the alternative is explicitly selected in that bean archive. An alternative is never available for injection, lookup or EL resolution in a module that is not a bean archive."

Comment: That quote is from CDI 1.0 spec? In CDI 1.2 spec: "This specification defines two methods of selecting alternatives. From Contexts and Dependency Injection 1.1 onwards the @Priority annotation allows an alternative to be selected for an entire application. Contexts and Dependency Injection 1.0 allowed only for an alternative to be selected for a bean archive."

Comment: @Priority(100) has to be at class level. Then it works!

Comment: Just curious. But doesn't the enabled `@Alternative` override the default producer when it's present?

Comment: @areus: Yes it would. Perhaps the default producer is also available but with higher priority? I really don't know...

Comment: @user39950: Updated answer, can you confirm it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the default producer, and don't know if it will be present at runtime, you will have to use the `@Any` qualifier and `Instance` as injection point to resolve the bean at runtime.

Try this:

1. Define a qualifier for your fallback producer, so it's not the default producer. You already did that, but instead of `@FooProducer` I would use something more meaningful like `@Fallback`.

   @Produces 
   @Fallback
   public Foo produce()
2. Change your injection point to `Instance<Foo>` and use the qualifier `@Any`.

   @Any
   private Instance fooProvider;
3. To get the Foo instance at runtime you will have to check if the instance is ambiguous. If it is, select the default producer, otherwise it will return the only available producer, the one you annotated with `@Fallback`.

   AnnotationLiteral defaultLiteral  = new AnnotationLiteral<>() {};

   Foo foo = fooProvider.isAmbiguous() ? 
           fooProvider.select(defaultLiteral).get() : 
           fooProvider.get();

With CDI 2.0 you can use `Default.Literal.INSTANCE` instead of `defaultLiteral`.